# Javascript confirmation in play framework scala templates

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0

I was wondering if there is a way to use a traditional javascript confirmation box with the scala html templates in the play framework.

```
@for(item <- listItems) {
            <li>
                <b>Item: </b>@item.name<br>

                @form(routes.Application.deleteItem(item.id)) {
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
                }
            </li><br>
        }
```

That is the view I am working with at the minute. As you can see from the code it brings up list of "item" objects and a delete button appears beside each of them. I just wanted to prompt some sort of confirmation dialog before the deleteItem method actually gets called.

I know how to do this with some standard HTML and javascript but thats only for modifying html elements, is there away to do this using the play form helpers?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not? :)

Actually I think you don't need to use single field form for this task, you can just use common link (of course it should point to GET route, also consider adding some hash to params, to prevent accidental deleting):

```
<a href="@routes.Application.deleteItem(item.id)" 
   class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete</a>
```